# Incorrect field of a content type in its display after migrating from a backup

Tags: 7, entities, database, display-suite

**The following two screen shots should explain the issue well:**

[image]

---

[image]

Here I have a content type **Poll**, where the first field is **Question** with machine name `title`. However, in **Managage Display** tab, *the second screen shot*, the first field is named **ShareThis**. I'm sure that there is a problem has been occurred during migration. I have tried to fix the database using `mysqlcheck -u root -p --auto-repair -o` and I tried to look at tables of the database itself using phpMyAdmin to find any hint or solution but I could not find. This issue is found also in another content type named **Photos**.
Is there any way to fix this databases fault? I'm using Drupal 7.

> ### Important Notice:
>
> In all contents types, in **Manage display** tab, the *title* field is named ShareThis. i.e it is not only in Photos type.

### Notice 2:

I observed also, the issue is not dedicated to *title* field only, it is extended to *URL path & Metatags* modules too. i.e the effected modules are Node, Path module and Meta Tag module. I have tried to create new Content Type, and also this issue appeared with it too.

[image]

Comment: Did you try re-importing?

Comment: @NoSssweat Do you mean re-import the database again?

Comment: yes, re-import db.

Comment: Yes, I re imported it again and the same issue still the same. I think that it is missing or corrupted foreign key in the database but I could not able to determine in any table! @NoSssweat